# Img not scaling when hovered

Tags: html, css

Good Afternoon Experts,

I'm having an issue with getting image to scale on hover. I've checked other thread and nothing seems to work for me. From what I've learned from other thread is that images scaling don't work on inline elements. Thus, I've tried including `display:inline-block` into my .banner-left-img class and .left class. However, it didn't work out for me.

I've tried transform with contrast, filter, and etc .. no issue but with scaling it becomes a problem.

What am I not understanding?

```css
.banner .left {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    background: var(--primary2-color);
    z-index: 2;
}

.banner .left .banner-left-img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: -150%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 145%;
    animation: 0.75s ease-in forwards imgSlideFromLeft;
}

@keyframes imgSlideFromLeft {
    100% {
        top: 50%;
        left: 7%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
}

.banner-left-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
    <div class="left">
        <img class ="banner-left-img" src="/img/banner/banner.png" alt="Mercedes AMG GT R Car Img">

        <a href="#"><img class ="social instagram" src="/img/social-media/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram icon"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csAXruiBLTs&ab_channel=Mercedes-Benz"><img class ="social youtube" src="/img/social-media/youtube.svg" alt="Youtube Icon"></a>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>the all new 2020<br>mercedes amg GT R</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nibh nisi tempor ipsum, mattis cursus
                gravida aenean dolor. Fermentum pharetra et habitasse netus gravida nibh. Est velit elementum nisl,
                tortor at elementum nulla. Egestas cras purus hendrerit aenean fermentum. </p>
            <button type="button">test drive now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What browser and OS?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS chrome.

Comment: This should help you to answer your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411191/3825777 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908175/3825777

Comment: Please post the answer and also try to remove information that is a distraction to others that might want to solve the same problem for themselves.

Comment: Yikes accidentaly deleted the comment. I'm posting it now! :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work my transform. The problem with it was with the selector where by hover was misplaced.

instead of `.banner-left-img:hover { transform: scale(1.5); }`

it should be `.banner .left:hover .banner-left-img { transform: translateY(-50%) scale(1.05); }`

I'll like to thank jQueryHtmlCSS for sharing other thread which helped me solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
width:100px; 
height: auto;
```

OR

```
height: auto; 
width: auto; 
max-width: 100px; 
max-height: 100px;
```

Comment: I tried this 

height: auto;
width: auto;
max-width: 135%;

It works .. However, it doesn't work if I scale it higher than the img original width which is 145% as stated on ".banner .left .banner-left-img" selector